# Организация юнит-тестов в Qt

Tags: qt, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Добрый день всем, я совсем недавно стал пользоваться unit-тестами при разработке на Qt, но появился вопрос: Как добавлять тесты в проект не вызывая беспорядка?

Я добавляю тесты через контекстное меню "File" -> "New File or Project..." - "Other Project" -> "Qt Unit Test". В результате у меня создается отдельный проект с одним тестом (из [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146449/) на хабре я узнал, что это такой подход Qt к тестированию). Но по мере роста проекта добавляется огромное количество тестов, которые вносят хаос в структуру папок. Я пробовал создать папку для тестов в текущем проекте и складывать все тесты туда, но я не знаю как запустить все unit-тесты разом при компиляции.

А еще, не могли бы вы накидать туториалов по юнит-тестированию на Qt (желательно на русском)?

Answer (score 2):

Огромное количество тестов - это само по себе неплохо. Разбивайте их по директориям, если не нравится их скопление в одном месте.

Отдельный исполняемый файл для каждого теста - это один из возможных вариантов. Другой вариант - запускать сразу несколько тестов, примерно так (по хорошему надо ещё возвращать ненулевой код в случае падения одного из тестов):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestFoo testFoo;
    QTest::qExec(&testFoo);

    TestBar testBar;
    QTest::qExec(&testBar);

    TestBaz testBaz;
    QTest::qExec(&testBaz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы исполнялись все тесты в момент билда проекта? И как дать понять Qt как организовано расположение моих тестов?

Ваш пример кажется мне громоздким, т.к. тесты придется запихивать в main-функцию основного проекта. По мне, как-то не логично, что тесты будут находиться внутри программы.

Comment: Это `main` для исполняемого файла тестов (не для основного приложения). Как пример, что в одном исполняемом файле можно запускать несколько тестов.